# Float and auto width problem CSS

Tags: css, css-float, width

My code is

```
<body>
   <div class="main>
      <div class="left">blah blah </div>
      <div class="right">blah blah </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS part:

```
.main{min-width:1000px}
.left{width:400px ; height:auto ; float:left }
.right{width:auto ; height:auto ;float:left }
```

I am dynamically inserting data into 'right' div and when its width exceeds 600px , it comes down the left div. But instead of that I want a horizontal scrollbar to view the content. One solution may be, removing "float:left" from right div. But still it causes problem.

Comment: What happens, if you use `overflow: scroll;` on the right `<DIV>`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "word-wrap" css property. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).
But if you still want to keep your way, you can use `max-width: 600px;` and `overflow: auto;` css properties for your right div. I assume it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm it does not make sense the layout you just presented for a number of reasons but it's your site so you probably have your reasons .
But given this context all you have to do is :

A fluid layout is always better , even if you're using a fixed div as a wrapper .

```
.left{
width:40% ; 
float:left ; 
}

.right{ 
width:60% ;
overflow : scroll ;
}
```

But you should be more precise , i don't clearly get what are you trying to achieve but this will probably solve your problem .
And remember if you use fluid widths margins,padding and borders can mess your layout . But that's another story .

EDIT:
See i didn't understood the first time what were trying to achieve , you probably were looking for : " The padding with the negative margin trick " to get everything to the same height :

```
 .main{overflow:hidden}
 .left{
    width:40% ; 
    float:left ; 
    padding-bottom : 1000px ; 
    margin-bottom : -1000px;
    }

    .right{ 
    width:60% ;
    float:left ;
    padding-bottom : 1000px ; 
    margin-bottom : -1000px; 
    }
```

Comment: I am dividng body into two parts. left and right. By not setting "float:left" in class 'right'. The content of right div starts going beneath left, Some content (equivalent to height of left div) remains at correct position, remaining starts going beneath left part,which I dont want. any suggestions ?

Comment: See i didn't understood the first time  ,.main{min-width:1000px , overflow:hidden }
.left{width:400px ; padding-bottom : 600px ; margin-bottom: -600px ; float:left }
.right{width:auto ; padding-bottom : 600px ; margin-bottom: -600px ; ;float:left } This will solve your problem . remember to adjust the padding and the margin to the size you need . I assumed 600 px is enough .

Comment: By adding a padding and a negative margin on the bottom your child divs will expand properly . Hope that helped .